# Is it acceptable to change affiliation to new employer when submitting an updated manuscript when old employer provided limited research support?

Tags: publications, affiliation

**Background:** I have published a paper with no co-authors in a CS workshop a few months ago. I have put as my affiliation the place in which I was lecturing at that time, say university X. The work was made by myself, with no use of resources from my previous place of work. I applied for some financial help to cover the expenses that I suffered (registration for the workshop, tickets and accommodation), but they agreed only to give at most the 10% of the expenses roughly. This amount has not yet been paid.

I now work at a new university that is research oriented; and there is the opportunity to submit the research paper that I was doing to a journal, after some modifications. So I was wondering:

**Is it acceptable to change my affiliation from my old university to the new university when submitting an updated manuscript?**

This is mainly because the former one did not bring any kind of support for this research activity.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend to use both. If the journal differentiates "address" and "current address", then:

- "address" is X (where you did the research)
- "current address" is Y (that's where people can reach you now, right?)

If the journal doesn't distinguish them, I would put Y first (you seem to consider Y more important). If the journal doesn't allow two affiliations, them the journal is strange; just try to put both affiliations in the one field and see what happens.